# Limit the user to give the test only once

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I want to limit the student to attempt specific test once.
There can be multiple quizzes but each student should be giving test once only.
The student field is one to one field with user

```
@login_required(login_url='studentlogin')
@user_passes_test(is_student)
def calculate_marks_view(request):
    if request.COOKIES.get('course_id') is not None:
        course_id = request.COOKIES.get('course_id')
        course=QMODEL.Course.objects.get(id=course_id)
        total_marks=0
        questions=QMODEL.Question.objects.all().filter(course=course)
        for i in range(len(questions)):
            selected_ans = request.COOKIES.get(str(i+1))
            actual_answer = questions[i].answer
            if selected_ans == actual_answer:
                total_marks = total_marks + questions[i].marks
        student = models.Student.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
        result = QMODEL.Result()
        result.marks=total_marks
    
        result.exam=course
        result.student=student
        result.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('view-result')
```

(Edited)
I'm giving the models that I used in this .
The models used are as follows :
Student :~

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic= models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pic/Student/',null=True,blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=False)

    @property
    def get_name(self):
        return self.user.first_name+" "+self.user.last_name
    @property
    def exams_taken(self):
        return [r.course for r in Result.objects.get(student=self)]
    @property
    def get_instance(self):
        return self
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name
```

Quiz :~

```
class Course(models.Model):
   course_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   question_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   total_marks = models.PositiveIntegerField()



   def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name

class Question(models.Model):
    course=models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    marks=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    question=models.CharField(max_length=600)
    option1=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    option2=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    option3=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    option4=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cat=(('Option1','Option1'),('Option2','Option2'),('Option3','Option3'),('Option4','Option4'))
    answer=models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=cat)

class Result(models.Model):

    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    marks = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The template for exam that I used is given as follows:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h6 class="panel-title">Courses</h6>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-hover" id="dev-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>

          <th>Exam Name</th>

          <th>Take Exam</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {% for t in courses %}
      <tr>

        <td> {{t.course_name}}</td>


        <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="{% url 'take-exam' t.id  %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></a></td>




      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

I want to show the button only to new user

<td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="{% url 'take-exam' t.id  %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></a></td>
```

Comment: You store which student took which test. A unique constraint can enforce this even on database level.

Comment: I think what your looking for needs a database you will need a table for students and one for quiz and a many to many relation that will generate table called didtest  and then before he can enter this exam you will launch a query that checks if his id and this test id are found together in didtest if yes you prevent him from going in (by warning whatever) else he can do his exam and you will direct him to the exam page

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your code example, each course has one exam and each student should be able to take each of the exams once. Looks like you already have a model `Result` that stores the relation between the student and each exam or course. You could simply check if such an object already exists for the combination of the user and the course.

```
class Student(model):
  [...]
  
  @property
  def exams_taken(self):
    return [r.course for r in Result.objects.get(student=self)]
```

(I'm pretty sure there is a more elegant way to do use the query language instead of the list comprehension..)

In your template you could simply check each exam to be in this list.

```
{% for t in courses %}
  <tr>
    <td> {{t.course_name}}</td>
    <td>
      {% if t in student.exams_taken %}
        <span> already taken </span>
      {% else %}
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="{% url 'take-exam' t.id  %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></a>
      {% endif %}
</td>
{% endfor %}
```

have not tested the code and did a lot of assumtions to find a solution that fits your needs perfectly more Information as the definition of your current models could be helpful.

And make sure your exam view checks if the student has taken the exam from the database. Checking the cookies or hiding the button does not prevent "creative" people from taking the exam again.

Comment: I have tried with your solution. But somehow it didn't worked.

Comment: I have added some more details. might get something